# Qt 4.8.5 -- error compiling ResourceFile.qrc

Tags: linux, qt

I have Qt installed in my virtual Machine Linux. My Qt project is compiling for X11 Desktop.

I am having a resource file in my QT project -- `AutosResourceFile.qrc`
I am getting a compilation error in this file when i compile the project.

> Error : Virtual memory exahausted

Please see the attached image.

How to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this qrc file is quite big, so memory isn't enough. Try to give more memory to this virtual machine and don't run (on guest OS) other programs while you're compiling.

Comment: Increasing virtual machine size resolved the problem .